# MVC Attribute and OpenID Connect token

Tags: jwt, attributes, authorization, microservices

We are trying to migrate our monolith to Microservice architecture. Our Microservices are using a User service to authenticate the user. The User-Service generates JWT-token, which contains all roles that user has.

Our developers have created one custom MVC Attribute which extracts the token and authorizes the user. The attribute has been added in front of all our methods in all our Microservices. The information from database that the attribute uses to authorize the user has been cached.

My question is; using one single attribute for all methods and microservices, doesn't it lead to an expensive authorization process? What is the best approach?

Comment: what .net framework are you using for microservices? can you not use middleware with [ASP Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)?

Comment: If you don't like to query the database for authorization you should consider using  [claims-based authorization](https://kariera.future-processing.pl/blog/introduction-to-claims-based-authentication-and-authorization-in-net/). definitely, it will be lighter and faster.

Comment: Rami Assi; we have used Claims-based authorization. So the token consists of claims, for example (role1, role2), but when you go to a method (function), you need to make some check against the database.